# External sites link https issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a video website which I recently changed from http to https.

i.e http://example.com to https://www.example.com.

And I have also made an htaccess entry to automatically 301 redirect all http urls to https.

The old video embed code links given to external customer sites are like :

```
<script scr="http://example.com/embed_script.js"></script>
```

Some customer websites also changed to http to https. In those https websites the above link with http protocol won't work because of mixed content. I have no control over the customer sites to change those urls to https. Any automatic redirect solution exists for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix this unless you get them to use https.  You could perhaps locally cache a copy as a workaround, but I've never done that.